# ASP.Net: Validating Radio Button Input with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, radiobuttonlist

I'm running into issues creating a Custom Validator input for my radio button list. I've coded everything out and everything runs without a problem. It's just nothing happens when the validation is supposed to occur. My other validations work just fine.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="SalaryPaidByEFT" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="width-100 radio">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Not Applicable" Value="null" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvSalaryPaidByEFT" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Salary Must Be Paid By EFT" ControlToValidate="SalaryPaidByEFT"
    OnServerValidate="cvSalaryPaidByEFT_ServerValidate" CssClass="has-error"
    Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
protected void cvSalaryPaidByEFT_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (this.SalaryPaidByEFT.SelectedIndex == 0);
}
```

Can anyone spot anything I may be missing to guide me to a solution?

Comment: OnServerValidate="cvSalaryPaidByEFT_ServerValidate" and the name of the method doesn't match cvHasOwnIncomeAccount_ServerValidate. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Edited my question, still receiving the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing a call to the this.Validate() method and checking of IsValid property of the page.. From msdn example:

```
if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    this.Validate();
    if (!this.IsValid)
    {
        string msg = "";
        // Loop through all validation controls to see which
        // generated the errors.
        foreach (IValidator aValidator in this.Validators)
        {
            if (!aValidator.IsValid)
            {
                msg += "<br />" + aValidator.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
        Label1.Text = msg;
    }
}
```

You may be missing the step 4 on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx) msdn instruction for custom validator.

step 4 -"Add a test in your ASP.NET Web page code to check for validity. For details, see How to: Test Validity Programmatically for ASP.NET Server Controls."

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

```
this.SalaryPaidByEFT.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes"
```

or

```
args.Value == "Yes"
```

Comment: Sorry I made an error while copying my error, it's still not working.

Comment: When do you expect validation to happen?

Comment: Upon submission, like my required field validators work

Comment: Ok, then are you calling the Page.Validate() method somewhere in your code behind and does the submit button have the CausesValidation set to true?